# Get current contiuation in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats, continuations, callcc, cps

Haskell has a function for getting the current continuation

```
getCC = callCC (\c -> let x = c x in return x)
```

How to write a similar function in Scala?

E.g. function `callCC` presents in cats.ContT. How could we use it?

I've tried many ways, but I can't make ends meet..

Comment: What is the meta-problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I've seen interesting examples of using `getCC` in Haskell, for example the implementation of goto-pattern (backward). In general, `getCC` reveals interesting features of `callCC`. I'd like to try them in Scala. Unfortunatly, poor knowledge of Haskell makes it difficult to understand how to transfer this to Scala.

Comment: I haven't tested the code but my best effort at tackling the problem of implementing `getCC` is https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ou4HKe6IT0ipLItwpCilUQ - if it works I could try to explain my thought process... but IMHO it shows why this style of programming doesn't work in Scala.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok thanks a lot! It works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4gH9t2FXRnu8yqlXW30lVw
But it has some issues with closures... minor, I hope.

Comment: "this style of programming doesn't work in Scala." Could you please explain what do you mean?

Comment: OTOH: it only used by (some) effect library authors, for everyone else it's too opaque (something doesn't work and your junior sees functions which call themselves, good luck explaining this); it's presence in Scala (or any other OOP) codebases is more of a trivia than anything impactful, so there are no sources nor tribal knowledge; if it breaks, forget about debugging stack traces; finally, type inference works different in Scala and in Haskell, so even for this example I had to investigate what combination of type params would yield type checking code, while Haskell resolves it for you.

Comment: Basically, it is a nice intellectual exercise for broadening your horizons, an experiment for figuring out possibilities for the next better runtime, but right now using it on JVM will result in some very developer hostile codebase.

Comment: A lot of useful things in Scala are based on CPS: `Resource` from the Cats library, some Algebraic Effects libraries, "Direct Style", etc. So I think this is a good direction for "broadening horizons")) Thanks again!

Comment: They are, but they are hiding these implementation details from the user, and they do a lot of work to e.g. [remove noise from stack traces when you get exception inside IO](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/docs/tracing). `ContT` and friends _encourage you_ to work with these internals and require to do a lot of type inference that Scala is not suitable for - I spend yesterday _literally 5h_ to figure out what needs to be done to make this code work, while in Haskell it's a one liner and "lol, compiler figured it out for me". It was fun - as a one time puzzle - but I'd hate doing it everyday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's implement this `getCC` ("get current continuation") in Scala.

For starters, let's understand what is actually happening in Haskell. When we look at the docs and sources we'll find:

```hs
newtype ContT (r :: k) (m :: k -> Type) a // or
newtype ContT r m a = ContT { runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r }

class Monad m => MonadCont (m :: Type -> Type) where
  callCC :: ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> m a

instance forall k (r :: k) (m :: (k -> Type)) . MonadCont (ContT r m) where
  callCC = ContT.callCC

MonadCont (ContT r m)
  callCC :: ((a -> ContT r m b) -> ContT r m a) -> ContT r m a
```

So what we see here:

- we are defining a `newtype`, a way of using an existing type, giving it a new name and then hiding from the rest of the code the actual type, so that all interaction with that type will go only through our API - Scala 3's counterpart would be `opaque type`, but in the past it was often done with wrappers extending AnyVal, or sometimes plain wrappers. Cats' decided to use a plain class:

  ```
  // counterpart to
  //   newtype ContT r m a = ContT { runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r }
  // where
  //   r becomes A
  //   m becomes M[_]
  //   a becomes +B
  //   runContT :: (a -> m r) -> m r becomes protected def runAndThen: AndThen[B => M[A], M[A]]
  sealed abstract class ContT[M[_], A, +B] extends Serializable {
    final def run: (B => M[A]) => M[A] = runAndThen
    protected def runAndThen: AndThen[B => M[A], M[A]]
    // ...
  }
  ```
- but we are not defining all that continuation magic for `ContT` type only, no, we are creating a separate type class `MonadCont` which defines function `callCC`, and you could provide an instance for various different types. `ContT` is just one of them. If we wanted to express it in Scala 3, it would be:

  ```
  trait MonadCont[M[_]: Monad]:
    def callCC[A, B](f: (A => M[B]) => M[A]): M[A]

  object MonadCount:
    // If you are comparing the code:
    // Haskell uses name r like result
    given [R]: MonadCont[[A] =>> ContT[M, R, A]] with
      def callCC[A, B](f: (A => ContT[M, R, B]) => ContT[M, R, A]): ContT[M, R, A] = ???
  ```
- in Cats however things are a bit simpler, so `callCC` is defined directly in `ContT` companion object, and it is defined only for `ContT` so it looks like this:

  ```
  def callCC[M[_], A, B, C](f: (B => ContT[M, A, C]) => ContT[M, A, B])(implicit M: Defer[M]): ContT[M, A, B] =
  ```
- just by comparing the code we can see, that when Haskell code uses generic `m` in context of `ContT[M, R, A]` it is NOT just `M` but WHOLE `ContT[M, R, *]`

Ok, so let's move to `getCC` part:

- `getCC` is defined in Haskell more or less as

  ```
  getCC: m -> m (m a)
  getCC = callCC (\c -> let x = c x in return x)
  ```
- that `m -> m (m a)` is important but only with the knowledge that `m` is `ContT[M, R, *]` we can actually decode the type signature, and what it would look like in Scala:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_], R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] = ???
  ```
- now we must use types to guide our implementation. We'll start with some stubs:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    // We'll start with abstract types, and then figure out
    // the concrete types that would make them work
    type X
    type Y
    type Z
    // reminder what callCC signature looked like:
    // def callCC[M[_], A, B, C](f: (B => ContT[M, A, C]) => ContT[M, A, B])(implicit M: Defer[M]): ContT[M, A, B]
    ContT.callCC[M, X, Y, Z] { (c: (Y => ContT[M, X, Z]) =>
      // I only created this val to annotate the returned type.
      // We'll get rid of it soon.
      val result: ContT[M, X, Y]) = ???

      result 
    }
  ```
- but we know what our `result` type has to be - `ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]]` - so what values of `X` and `Z` would make it type check?

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    type X = R
    type Y = ContT[M, R, A]
    type Z
    ContT.callCC[M, X, Y, Z] { (c: (Y => ContT[M, X, Z]) =>
      // this is: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]]
      val result: ContT[M, X, Y]) = ???

      result 
    }
  ```
- let's substitute `X` and `Y` and eliminate type aliases:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    type Z
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], Z] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, Z]) =>
      val result: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]]) = ???

      result 
    }
  ```
- before we figure out `Z` we need to stop for a moment. The implementation code was:

  ```
  getCC = callCC (\c -> let x = c x in return x)
  ```

  We have to be reminded that in Haskell `return` is a function from `Monad` typeclass used to... wrap the value returned in `do` comprehension. In other word it's what Cats knows as `def pure` method in the `Monad` type class. So that lets us adjust the code to this:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    type Z
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], Z] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, Z]) =>
      val x = ???

      val result: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]]) = ContT.pure(x)

      result 
    }
  ```
- further analysis of types lets us figure out the types that needs to be passed into `pure` to get the expected `result` - in particular what is `x`:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    type Z
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], Z] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, Z]) =>
      val x: ContT[M, R, A] = ???

      // we can drop "val result = ...; result" from now on
      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }
  ```
- so far, so good, now we only need to figure out how `x` comes to be and what is `Z`. The hint is in Haskell definition: `let x = c x`. Lets try to write it in Scala:

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    type Z
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], Z] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, Z]) =>
      val x: ContT[M, R, A] = c(x) // doesn't compile

      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }
  ```
- putting compiler warnings aside (using `val x` in its own definition is not allowed) this code would make sense if `c` method returned `ContT[M, R, A]]`... but it returns `ContT[M, R, Z]]`... so `Z = A`

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], A] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, A]) =>
      val x: ContT[M, R, A]] = c(x) // still doesn't compile

      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }
  ```
- now we only have to solve the last issue - make `val x = c(x)` compile. The problem comes from an eager evaluation - in Haskell everything is lazy, so there is no such issue that when we evaluate `x` we are immediately calling `c(x)`, but to evaluate `c(x)` we need to know the value of `x`, etc. It's one of the reasons why `ContT` uses `Defer[M]` a lot - to introduce that lazy evaluation which would let you create the value without a circular dependency in its initialization. So, lets just use some way of deferring the *content*  of `x` but still creating a *reference* to `x`. One such way I found was through `lazy val` and `ContT.later` (which happens to take as by-name param, what `.run` is returning):

  ```
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], A] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, A]) =>
      lazy val x: ContT[M, R, A] = ContT.later(c(x).run)

      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }
  ```

Then you can make this method an extension method on `ContT` companion object, e.g. for Scala 3 it would be

```
extension (contT: ContT.type)
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], A] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, A])) =>
      lazy val x: ContT[M, R, A] = ContT.later(c(x).run)

      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }
```

and as [you already verified](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/4gH9t2FXRnu8yqlXW30lVw) it works:

```
import cats.data.ContT
import cats.Defer

extension (contT: ContT.type)
  def getCC[M[_]: Defer, R, A]: ContT[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]] =
    ContT.callCC[M, R, ContT[M, R, A], A] { (c: (ContT[M, R, A] => ContT[M, R, A])) =>
      lazy val x: ContT[M, R, A] = ContT.later(c(x).run)

      ContT.pure[M, R, ContT[M, R, A]](x)
    }

// Testing

import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.unsafe.implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.{Duration, MILLISECONDS}
import java.time.LocalDateTime

val start = LocalDateTime.now()

// It ticks for some times
def loop =
  for {
    gotoLabel <- ContT.getCC[IO, Unit, Unit]
    _         <- ContT.liftF(IO.sleep(Duration(1000, MILLISECONDS)))
    _         <- ContT.liftF(IO.println("Tick"))
    now       <- ContT.liftF(IO{LocalDateTime.now()})
    _ <-      if (now.getSecond % 20 != 0) gotoLabel
              else                         ContT.liftF(IO.unit)
  } yield ()
  
loop.run(_ => IO.println("Done")).unsafeRunSync()
```

I would not be completely sure it always works - I'd suggest putting a lot of tests precisely because we have to manually address this eager vs lazy value problem ourselves, but it should pretty much explain the idea.

Notice, how much effort went into manually resolving all kind of type parameters. (And in understanding what is going on in general, it's pretty counterintuitive, and I have to learn this style anew every time I meet it again.) In Haskell type resolution works in a different way and it allows to just skip it (what other issues it brings I'll leave to Haskellers to explain). But it is definitely opaque to read, hard to debug, and difficult to maintain. I may see its use case in some internal logic that only a few people have to tinker with (and only if it actually brings some value!), but I'd definitely recommend against using it commonly in codebase and in business logic.